# Cannot show data in EasyUI datagrid

Tags: jquery-easyui

I want to show some data in a popup dialog with EasyUI.

I'm sure I have got the data from the server, and I have checked that the `field` is consistent with the `field` in the Java class, but I still got a blank dialog.

**My JS Code:**

```
function viewECReportSpec(ecspecName, ecreportSpecName) {
    $('#viewECReportSpec').dialog({
        title : ecreportSpecName + '@' + ecspecName,
        width : 800,
        height : 400,
    });
    $("#viewECReportSpec").dialog('open');

    $('#viewECReportSpecParams').datagrid({
        url : basePath + '/rmws/alereading/getECReportSpec.do',
        queryParams : {
            ecspecName : ecspecName,
            ecreportSpecName : ecreportSpecName
        },
        columns : [[{
            field : 'reportName',
            title : 'Report Name',
            formatter : function(val) {
                alert(val);
            }
        }]],
    });
}
```

I can get the correct `reportName` from the alert in `formatter`, but the dialog shows nothing.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You should generate the dialog after the data is retrieved. I do not see any part of your code that actually puts the data in the dialog, so it seems normal that it is empty. Try something like the following:

```
function viewECReportSpec(ecspecName, ecreportSpecName) {
    $('#viewECReportSpecParams').datagrid({
        url : basePath + '/rmws/alereading/getECReportSpec.do',
        queryParams : {
            ecspecName : ecspecName,
            ecreportSpecName : ecreportSpecName
        },
        columns : [[{
            field : 'reportName',
            title : 'Report Name',
            formatter : function(val) {
                alert(val);
            }
        }]],
        onLoadSuccess : function(data) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = data;
            $(div).dialog({
                title : ecreportSpecName + '@' + ecspecName,
                width : 800,
                height : 400,
            });
        },
    });
}
```